# Apache VirtualHosts for a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, apache2, virtualhost

On a server there is already a site running. I'm trying to make my rails app run on a url of the same site i.e the site is example.com and the rails app will run at example.com/railsapp.

The rails app will use passenger and the server is ubuntu.
The current virtualhosts file looks like;

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/examplesite/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymlinks Multiviews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Do I need to add a separate hosts file?

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
 ServerName ??? 
 DocumentRoot /var/www/railsapp/public
 <Directory /var/www/railsapp/public> 
  AllowOverride all 
  # MultiViews must be turned off. 
  Options -MultiViews 
 </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm not sure what to do...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proper solution is documented in the [Deploying to a sub URI](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#deploying_rails_to_sub_uri) Passenger documentation:

Suppose that you already have a virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.phusion.nl
    DocumentRoot /websites/phusion
    <Directory /websites/phusion>
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And you want your Rails application, located in `/websites/rails`, to be accessible from the URL `http://www.phusion.nl/subapp`.

To do this, you need to perform the following:

1. Set `Alias {SUBURI} {PATH TO YOUR APPLICATION'S PUBLIC DIRECTORY}`.
2. Create a `<Location /{SUBURI}>` block.
3. Inside the `Location` block, set `PassengerBaseURI /{SUBURI}`.
4. Inside the `Location` block, set `PassengerAppRoot {PATH TO YOUR APPLICATION ROOT}`.
5. Create a `<Directory {PATH TO YOUR APPLICATION'S PUBLIC DIRECTORY}>` block.
6. Inside the `Directory` block, set `Allow from all`.
7. Inside the `Directory` block, disable `MultiViews`.

Here is an example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.phusion.nl
    DocumentRoot /websites/phusion
    <Directory /websites/phusion>
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    # These have been added:
    Alias /subapp /websites/rails/public
    <Location /subapp>
        PassengerBaseURI /subapp
        PassengerAppRoot /websites/rails
    </Location>
    <Directory /websites/rails/public>
        Allow from all
        Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Apache is refusing to start because PassengerBaseURI is an invalid command. Is this documentation out of date?

Comment: @XanderStrike you must be on passenger > v4 i think. what version are you on?

Comment: Wow this was a while ago. I worked it out, I had forgotten to copy the module includes for passenger into my `smb.conf`.